# Timer.Tick doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm trying to move image on the panel with timer.tick but it doesn't work for some reason...
Timer is enabled in properties window and this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Image img;
    private Point pos;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        img = Image.FromFile("C:/object.png");
        pos = new Point(100, 100);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, pos);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos.X += 10;
        pos.Y += 10;

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I can't see what is the problem here?? :)

I also tried this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Image img;
    private Point pos;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        img = Image.FromFile("C:/object.png");
        pos = new Point(100, 100);

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Enabled = true; // don't know if this goes here
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MoveImg);
        myTimer.Interval = 100;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void MoveImg(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        pos.X += 10;
        pos.Y += 10;

        Invalidate();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are invalidating the wrong object, use panel1.Invalidate()

Comment: Works, thnks!!! But works only for second code...?

Comment: WPF != WinForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the timer using [`Timer.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    img = Image.FromFile("C:/object.png");
    pos = new Point(100, 100);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

And as **Hans Passant** says - you have to Invalidate the right object.

```
private void MoveImg(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    pos.X += 10;
    pos.Y += 10;

    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: No, still doesn't work for me. My code is step by step example from Youtube, and it works there for all the ppl somehow... I'll add something else that i tried.